# Different results in average, BASH

Tags: bash, average

This code is meant to give me the maximum value, the minimum value, and the average of the columns I input in the gene I want.

So, an example: "./script.sh 7 8 9 -g TAGLN" This code will give me the maximum, minimum and average of the columns 7 8 9 of gene TAGLN.

The problem here is that the average of the function output2() gives a wrong result... However, the average of function output1() is fine and I can't uderstand it...

```
#!/bin/bash

output1() {
    var1=$(cat affy.txt | cut -d"!" -f$i | sort -nr | head -1)
    echo "Maximum value of array ARRY$(($i-5|bc))X is $var1"
    var2=$(cat affy.txt | cut -d"!" -f$i | sort -nr | tail -1)
    echo "Minimum value of array ARRY$(($i-5|bc))X is $var2"
    var3=$(cat affy.txt | cut -d"!" -f$i | awk '{total += $1; count++ } END {print total/count}')
    echo -e "Average of array ARRY$(($i-5|bc))X is $var3 \n"
}

output2() {
    var1=$(grep $word affy.txt | cut -d"!" -f$i | sort -nr | head -1)
    echo "Maximum value of array ARRY$(($i-5|bc))X in gene $word is $var1"
    var2=$(grep $word affy.txt | cut -d"!" -f$i | sort -nr | tail -1)
    echo "Minimum value of array ARRY$(($i-5|bc))X in gene $word is $var2"
    var3=$(grep $word affy.txt | cut -d"!" -f$i | awk '{total += $1; count++ } END {print total/count}')
    echo -e "Average of array ARRY$(($i-5|bc))X in gene $word is $var3 \n"
}

function3() {
columns=""
for i in $@; do
    if [ $i = "-g" ]; then
        word=$2
        is_there_g="True"
        break
    else
        is_there_g="False"
        fi
        columns+="$i "
        shift
done
length="${#columns}"
echo $columns
}

deciding_the_output() {
function3 $@
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
    for i in `seq 5 20`; do
        output1 $i
    done
else
    if [ $is_there_g = "False" ]; then
    for i in $columns; do
        output1 $i
    done
    else
    if [ $length = 0 ]; then
        for i in `seq 5 20`; do
            output2 $i
        done
    else
        for i in $columns; do
            output2 $i
        done
    fi
    fi
fi
}

deciding_the_output $@
```

Comment: Are you sure bash is the right language for this?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of a wrong result and the text file and search word?

Comment: @user2886545 - Check the results of the 'grep $word' line for var3 before the cut/awk commands come into play. I bet the problem is in there.

Comment: I'd rather use Python, but it is an assignment from university, Adam.

Comment: You could do it all in awk, which can't break the rules since you do some of it in awk. Unless the rules are that you have to use as many command-line tools as possible.

Comment: By the way, what do you intend with `|bc` in `ARRY$(($i-5|bc))X`? I couldn't think of a plausible reason to bit-or `$bc` with `$i-5`

Answer (score 0):

If I type `./script.sh 8`, I'm looking for max, min and average of column 8 taking all the rows, and the result is correct:

```
Maximum value of array ARRY3X is 9,22055
Minimum value of array ARRY3X is -8,72615
Average of array ARRY3X is 0.441644
```

If I type `./script.sh 8 -g TAGLN`, I'm looking for max,min, and average of column 8 for the gene TAGLN, but the average given is wrong:

```
Maximum value of array ARRY3X in gene TAG is 1,91835
Minimum value of array ARRY3X in gene TAG is 1,68215
Average of array ARRY3X in gene TAG is 1
```

It gives always integers like 1, 0...

Comment: Is this an answer? If it adds info to your question, append it to the former question.